# How to add content to a PopupControl in JavaFX 2.2.6?

Tags: java, css, javafx-2

I want to implement a simple popup control, which should be styleable with CSS.
It's all working fine the only question is how to add content (a Node in JavaFX) to it?

The `PopupWindow.getContent()` method is deprecated in JavaFX 2.2.6 and not working with CSS, I am able to see the content but the CSS-selector will not work then.

So what is the best solution to add content myself, should I implement my own Skin class for that purpose or is there a simple way to just make it work?

I have prepared a simple use case:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PopupControl;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class PopupTest extends PopupControl {
    public PopupTest() {
        getStyleClass().add("popup"); // not working!?

        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.getStyleClass().add("pane");
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(250, 250);
        rectangle.getStyleClass().add("rect");
        Label text = new Label("popup test");
        text.getStyleClass().add("text");
        pane.getChildren().addAll(rectangle, text);

        // how to display to pane when the popup is shown?
        getContent().addAll(pane);
    }
}
```

For completeness here are my MainApplication and CSS file:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Group root = new Group();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(MainApplication.class.getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

        final Button button = new Button("show popup");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                PopupTest popup = new PopupTest();
                popup.show(scene.getWindow());

            }
        });
        root.getChildren().add(button);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

style.css:

```
.popup {
    -fx-font-size: 24px;
}

.popup .rect {
    -fx-fill: green;
}

.popup .text {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

The ".popup" selector is not working here, if I set it to the "pane" it will style the popup window so the css is correct: `pane.getStyleClass().add("popup"); // working with this "fix"`.

Comment: Have you tried javafx.stage.Popup?

Comment: I tried that one before, but essentially the Popup class is the same as PopupWindow, and PopupControl (also extends PopupWindow) also implements the javafx.scene.control.Skinnable interface which should make it style-able via CSS.

Answer (score 3):

That seems to work:

```
getScene().setRoot(pane);
```

About the style class not working: PopupControl doesn't have a `getStylesheets()` method. So maybe it can only be styled directly by `setStyle(...)`? You can work around that by simply styling `pane` or by wrapping `pane` in a root pane and styling that.